# Yii2 render two models in one view

Tags: yii2

Yii is the best but I'm have two models , book and author . I need to process two forms for each one in a single view , as I do this in yii2.0 .

```
      <?=
        $this->render('_formBook', array('model' => $model));
        ?>

          <?=
            $this->render('_formAuthor', array('model' => $model));
            ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this way

In your Controller

```
$modelBook = Book::findOne($id);
$modelAuthor  = Author::findOne($key);


  return $this->render('_formWithTheTwoForm', 
           'modelBook' => $modelBook, 
                  'modelAuthor' => $modelAuthor,]);
```

Then in your view you can use both the model