# Display data from from model without any relation in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have two Models 1. `Orders` 2. `Offers`. There's no relation between them. 
In the view file of `Order` I want to display the `of_name`,`of_desc` from the latest entry of `Offer` table.
My offer `searchModel` looks like:

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Offers::find()->orderBy(['of_id' => SORT_DESC])->one();;

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'of_id' => $this->of_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'of_name', $this->of_name])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'of_description', $this->of_description]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

In the controller action of `Order` I've tried -

```
public function actionPrintorders($id) {

        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $searchModel  = new OrdersSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data         = Orders::findOne($id);

        $searchModel1 = new OffersSearch();
        //$dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printorder', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
            'data'=> $data,
            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            //'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            //'model2' => $model2,
            //'period' => $period,

            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\"><u>Working Hours : </u></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">9:00am to 9:00pm</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">Friday Morning Closed</td>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Prop:      M.Sinha</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Orderslip'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader'=>['Amit Optical'], 
                'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
        //return $this->render('_printSalarystatement', ['s_period' => $s_period]);

    }
```

And tried to pass value in the order view like -

```
<h3 style="margin-bottom:0;margin-top:2;margin-left:2;"><strong><p class="text-center"><?php echo $searchModel1['of_name'];?></p></strong></h3>
```

There's no error but there's no output like this line either. Please tell me how to do it.

**Update**
I've tried the solution made here [Yii2 render two models in one view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144553/yii2-render-two-models-in-one-view)
But obviously stuck at `$key`. Not sure how to pass it.
My present controller action looks like below.

```
public function actionPrintorders($id) {

        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $searchModel  = new OrdersSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data         = Orders::findOne($id);

        $searchModel1 = new OffersSearch();
        $modelOffer  = Offers::findOne($key);
        //$dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printorder', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel'  => $searchModel,
            'data'=> $data,
            'searchModel1' => $searchModel1,
            'modelOffer'=>$modelOffer,
            //'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            //'model2' => $model2,
            //'period' => $period,

            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\"><u>Working Hours : </u></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">9:00am to 9:00pm</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"left\">Friday Morning Closed</td>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Prop:      M.Sinha</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Orderslip'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader'=>['Amit Optical'], 
                'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();

    }
```

Comment: What's the reason of not using the relation?

Comment: There's no relation actually. The Offer table should have some offer details which I need to print while printing the Orders  (read invoice).

Comment: @arogachev can you tell me how to do it? I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The error is at beginning of code, that it should be

```
public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Offers::find()->orderBy(['of_id' => SORT_DESC]);
```

without the ->one() at the end of $query var, because ActiveDataProvider needs \yii\db\ActiveQuery object.

Comment: the ->one() was supposed to limit the result to only one row.

Comment: use limit() method

Comment: I've changed the query to $query = Offers::find()->orderBy(['of_id' => SORT_DESC])->limit(1) . But still the same result. I'm not sure if I'm passing the data in correct way.